# Vuejs 3 Use the globalProperties in VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

Just a quick question,
I'm using VueJS 3 and VUEX state management.

```
app.config.globalProperties.store_id = '5f82da561622f55328d8baac'
```

this is the global property that I use and wondering how I can directly access it with VUEX.

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties

Answer (score 1):

You could define that `store_id` as state in your store which could be used in the store and also in any component you want :

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

// Create a new store instance.
const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      store_id: '5f82da561622f55328d8baac',
     //other state
    }
  },
  mutations: {
  
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if it was possilbe to access it from vuex this way.

Comment: You're welcome, since that config is shared and global it's recommended to be defined as vuex state